# Getting "Task was cancelled" while creating indexer in azure search for blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

While creating indexer for azure blob storage in azure search I am getting this "Task was canceled" error, no other detail provided.

It suddenly started to throw this error, it was working perfectly this morning.

Any idea what can cause this issue?

Comment: Please email me your service name at eugenesh at the usual Microsoft domain. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This probably a transient situation, but this is not a useful error message and we'd like to fix this. Please email me your search service name and roughly when you hit this error and we'll investigate. I'll add a comment explaining how to reach me.

Comment: Thanks @Eugene for replying, The service name is HarborObjectSearch, however now I am able to create the indexer, the error is gone. What i did is sclae up but that does not make any sense since we only has hundreds of document. But we are still getting this error when one of my indexer runs. I encountered this error while creating container is around 9:30 AM GMT 15th July. While running one of my indexer encounter this is at 23:37 PM GMT 15th July. It is working fine ever since but i am still curious what caused this